# Heroku mLab MongoDB admin user not authorized for query in Flask application

Tags: python, mongodb, heroku, flask, flask-mongoengine

I have this section of code, which is part of my Flask application. I am using `flask_mongoengine`.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = MongoEngine(app)

from .models import *


@app.context_processor
def inject_config():
    return dict(Config.objects.first(), version=version)
```

`Config` is a class within `.models` that extends Document.

```
class Config(Document):
    title = StringField()
    description = StringField()
    keywords = StringField()
    author = StringField()
    version = StringField()
    meta = {"collection": "web_config"}
```

Upon calling `Config.objects`, it's returning an error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: database error: not authorized for query on heroku_dptwtq1j.web_config
```

I'm logged in through the admin user. Why am I not authorized for query? Also, how do I authorize myself to query?

I have no trouble querying through another application that uses PyMongo, so why is it not working in Flask?

Comment: Interesting, I have the same problem today with PyMongo. it works with another app we have which is in NodeJS, but not in Python.
Have you found any solutions?

Comment: @Shayan The problem for me was in flask_mongoengine library. I switched to just the mongoengine library, and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks @Jonny, my problem was also similar, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, answering my own question: the issue was probably in the flask_mongoengine library. I switched to just mongoengine and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use flask_mongoengine there is a work around mentioned in https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/851 which fixed it for me (though not ideal)

From allanlei:
My work around is actually to patch flask-mongoengine.connection._resolve_settings() to pass the host=mongodb://.... to mongoengine.connect()

Thanks to Chuck from mLabs who helped me find it.